# Ruby on Rails collection_select changes depends on other in Form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on a project that allow customer to reserve (book) a room  in hotel on Ruby on Rails. I want the customer to specify The room type he want and according to his selection, I want to show the rooms list of this type.

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-5">
    <%= f.label :room_Type %> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <%= f.collection_select :room_type, Type.all, :id, :name, :prompt =>  true  %></div></div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-5">
    <%= f.label :room_Number %> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <%= f.collection_select :room_id, Room.all, :id, :number, :prompt => true  %>
    </div></div>
```

Now, I can show the list of room types from the database. I also can show the list of rooms from the database. I did some search about this and they said it can be done using JQuery or Ajax but, I don't know how to do it. Could you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

This solution can help you to understand the flow as well.
First you fire an ajax call to your controller. (Keep in mind that this url from the ajax call must exist in your routes).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#room_type").on('change', function(){
    $ajax({
      url: "populate_other_list",
      type: "GET",
      data: {room_type: $(this).val()},
      // Callbacks that will be explained
    })
  });
```

Next you make your action inside your controller.

```
def populate_other_list
  room_type = params[:room_type]
  @room = Room.find_by room_type: room_type
or    
  Pass Id from AJax of Type and find the room here from Type    
  @room = Type.find(params[:type_id).rooms // Call the association if exists    
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @room }
  end
end
```

With this, on your success callback of your ajax call, you get a JSON object with your list. So you need to clear the room number select and create the options and append to it.

```
// Ajax call
success: function(data) {
  $("#room_id").children().remove();
  // Create options and append to the list
}
// Rest of Ajax call
```

As you can see, i didn't put the code that create the options

Because its sim[ple javascript which can be easily find in stackoverflow
For hint it will be looks like below

```
$("#room_id").append("<option>" + /your value/ + "</option>");
```

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation. I have other question. Where should I put the ajax call (first one) and ajax call back (after success). You mean I define the url in routes like other pages using get ?

Comment: Yes you need to define it in routes as get and write the code in the assets/javascript directory.

Comment: Else you can use the predefine rails ajax format as well https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/ refer it

Comment: I understand the idea now. Thanks for your help, Tushar

Comment: Just post here any problem if you will face